# rosrun executable or found error

Tags: rosrun

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hi, I used to hydro distribution of ros. I take to following error therefore I leave no stone unturned unfortunately I didn't correct. how can I correct this error?

Thank you in advance.

**"$rosrun my_pcl_tutorial example input:=/narrow_stereo_textured/points2

[rosrun] Couldn't find executable named example below /home/esetron/catkin_ws/src/my_pcl_tutorial

[rosrun] Found the following, but they're either not files,

[rosrun] or not executable:

[rosrun] /home/esetron/catkin_ws/src/my_pcl_tutorial/src/example"**

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/182869/rosrun-executable-or-found-error/) by [hamdi](https://answers.ros.org/users/19435/hamdi/) on ROS Answers with karma: 73 on 2014-07-03

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I've usually seen users have this problem in a few cases:

- Your package isn't built - run catkin_make in your workspace
- You haven't added your excutable to your CMakeLists.txt - follow the tutorial for adding your executable to your CMakeLists.txt
- You executable is built, but it's in the wrong place - make sure you're calling catkin_package() before add_exectuable() in your CMakeLists.txt

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2014-07-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [hamdi](https://answers.ros.org/users/19435/hamdi/) on 2014-07-04**:
thank you Ahendrix, I forgot to do the third suggestion.